# Can someone explain in detail how mapping this array works step by step

Tags: arrays, sorting, dictionary

The original array: [ [3, 5], [9, 6], [3,1] ]

1) Make the first number in each mini array the smaller number and the second number in each mini array the bigger number
- [ [3, 5], [9, 6], [3,1] ] -> [[ 3,5], [6,9], [1,3]]

2) Sort the mini arrays by first number.
- [ [3,5], [6,9], [1,3] ] -> [ [1,3], [3,5], [6,9] ]

So [ [3, 5], [9, 6], [3,1] ] -> [ [1,3], [3,5], [6,9] ] by the end of the sorting transformation.

Can someone explain in a step by step, detailed, clear, concise way how to use array.map() to make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `map` to make the `nested array` `numbers` placed in increasing order, then apply `sort` based on `first number` in the nested array.

```js
const arr = [
  [3, 5],
  [9, 6],
  [3, 1]
];

const sortedArr = arr
    .map(([num1, num2]) => num2 < num1 ? [num2, num1] : [num1, num2])
    .sort(([arr1num1], [arr2num1]) => arr1num1 - arr2num1);

console.log(sortedArr);
```

-- Edit--

Result of map

```
[[3, 5], [6, 9], [1, 3]];
```

In the sort function, I'am doing array destructuring (see - https://javascript.info/destructuring-assignment). Basically, I'am only extracting the first element from array and storing in separate variable. In our case, `arr1num1` and `arr2num1`.

Example-

```js
const arr = [3, 5];

// Extracting the first element from array and saving in variable - arr1num1. 
// I do not need second array element 5, so i did not extracted the second array element
const [arr1num1] = arr; // arr1num1 will have now value 3
console.log(arr1num1);

// If second array element is also required, then the above statement will become const [num1, num2]  = arr; where num1 -> 3 and num2 ->5
```

Alternative, to above would be to directly access array elements using there index.

```js
const arr = [
    [3, 5],
    [9, 6],
    [3, 1]
 ];
  
 const sortedArr = arr
      .map(([num1, num2]) => num2 < num1 ? [num2, num1] : [num1, num2])
      .sort((arr1, arr2) => arr1[0] - arr2[0]);
  
console.log(sortedArr);
```

To know more about sort, see - [Sorting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

How sorting works,

In first iteration, swapping of [3, 5] & [6, 9] will happen based on sort condition.

```
arr1num1 -> 3
arr2num1 -> 6
```

The statement `arr1num1 - arr2num1` will check if `3` is greater than `6`. If yes, it will swap the arrays [3, 5] and [6, 9]. Since, 3 is not greater than 9, so no swapping will take place.

Second Iteration, swapping of [6, 9] and [1, 3] will take place based on condition.

```
arr1num1 -> 6
arr1num2 -> 1
```

Since, 6 > than 1, swapping will take place.

```
Before Swapping array will be- `[[3, 5], [6, 9], [1, 3]]`;
After Swapping array will be - `[[3, 5], [1, 3], [6, 9]]`;
```

This process will continue, until your array gets sorted.

Comment: I'd like to give you an acceptance, however I'd still like to understand this: What is a written out example of how the .sort portion of the code applies to this array of arrays?

Comment: Wouldn't it need to be arr1[num1], arr2[num1] ? Because arr1num1 represents [3, 5] yes? And arr2num1 represents [6, 9] yes? Or does arr1num1 represent 3, and arr2num1 represents 6? If arr1num and arr2num1 only represent the first number in the nested arrays, how does sort properly sequence the entire nested array

Comment: @AlexanderRostad - I have edited my answer. Please check. Sorry for delay in replay, I was busy with other stuff.